# Convert generic Collection to JSON string using JSONSimple in Java

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I have a non-typed collection of Entities and want to convert to JSON String, using JSONSimple.

I've tried with JSONObject like:

```
Collection entities; //supose its a non-typed Collection returned from service.
JSONObject colJSON = new JSONObject();
colJSON.put("entities",entities);
JSONValue.toJSONString(colJSON);
```

But, it just returns the Collection toString() method instead of the elements of the Collection;

Answer (score 0):

Try a List instead of Collection.  I don't see 'Collection' in J[SONSimple's supported type list](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/#Mapping_Between_JSON_and_Java_Entities).